# New manager said she has enough work to fill my schedule but hasn't confirmed

Tags: professionalism, management, time-management

**Background**

I work for various marketing agencies. The various agencies get different contracts from different clients who want their products promoted. Most agencies give only a few hours of work each week, so it's common to work for more than one agency at a time.

I've been working for Promote Me (name only used for convenience) for a little over a year now. There have been several changes in management. At the beginning of this month we got a new manager. I have had a few incidents with her. Being new some incidents are expected but the fact she doesn't explain, acknowledge or apologize is a  problem.

As a brief example: she asked if I left my shift. I said yes. She told me she hadn't told me I could go yet. This was a new rule to me and I told her that the instructions I got said I could leave when the work was over. She asked me who told me this and I said the previous manager. She asked if I had just called him. I said no, I've done this job before. This seems obvious - if she thought I was new then she would have given me all the instructions. I asked her to confirm if I should always check with her before leaving and she simply didn't reply.

Though she's knew to this position, the previous manager said she's done this work before. The work is very independent. I often don't work with other people and my only point of contact is this manager (who I often don't have the chance to meet face to face).

**Main Question**

The new manager sent me a text message asking what my availability is. I told her all of it. She replied by text "great, I booked you for these days. Please keep them open".

We have an app that has our shifts with all the info (like time, date, product and location) and we have a shared online calendar for this too. Aside from the text message, I have no information and it's not on the app or calendar. So I don't feel this is official. This is very uncomfortable because I'm turning down all other work but am skeptical the new manager has/will book me for all the days (it's rare to get so many at once).

I tried asking her about this but she hasn't replied to my messages. I have asked her about other things and she simply ignores. I contacted one of the old managers and asked her the contact info of her manager. He provided me with two email addresses. I emailed them both asking if I could speak with them over the phone. So far no reply.

I consider this an urgent matter because I need to have enough work so I can support myself. OTOH I don't want to miss a shift I am scheduled for with Promote Me.

Comment: What is the nature of your employment? Are you a contractor? Is there a minimum amount of notice you expect before being scheduled for a shift?

Answer (score 1):

> This is very uncomfortable because I'm turning down all other work but am skeptical the new manager has/will book me for all the days (it's rare to get so many at once). I tried asking her about this but she hasn't replied to my messages.

I would say you're right to be uncomfortable. Reading between the lines (no replies, rare that you'd be booked for that many days in a row, nothing official scheduled) I'd say she hasn't booked you at all, but wants you available at short notice *in case* she needs you.

If it were me, I'd start accepting other work on those days instead if it comes up, and then simply update your manager when you're no longer available. If she kicks up a fuss, you can simply state that you tried to clarify the situation earlier multiple times, but your messages were ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Inform your new manager via email that if the dates, times and companies which you will be working for are not confirmed on the app (it may be worthwhile to explain which app and how it was done before, in case she isn't aware)or through some other method you've got by this and this date, you will assume there is no real work there and accept other opportunities should they arise. Leave it at that. Don't send any more messages in regards to this matter, and of course accept any work you like after the agreed time.

Are there any other co-workers under her management? Are they facing the same issues? It may be worthwhile to investigate if she is trying to replace her whole team to get people who she chose, rather than the team of people already there. If you find that to be true, you might be forced to look for another job because she isn't going to let this go.